# Where can I find this document class

Tags: templates, document-classes

I need to write a report in this style 
https://www.casact.org/research/CPtemplate.doc

Since I have already written a report in a standard article documentclass, I would like to avoid re-write the whole thing.
So you guys know if there is a documentclass like the template?

Thank you very much,
Marco

Template screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please highlight which aspects you are interested in and what you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for our answer, I was just wondering if there is a documentclass similar to the one posted. I tried the different classes available under the documentclass function but no luck so far

Comment: Well, personally I will not open a Word document from a random source on the internet (because of the security risk), that's why I asked for specific features you are searching.

Comment: I do not know how to describe all the features here. The website is the CAS Website (Casualty Actuarial Society) a very reputable source

Comment: First of all: Have you talked with that company/institution that you are allowed to submit an article written in LaTeX. Then they can also tell you what to use ...

Comment: I added a screenshot for you (I feel quite safe opening docs in a sandboxed openoffice...) --- It seems quite easy to tackle in, for example, `memoir`.

Comment: Nothing you show there could not be achieved with the default classes. Have a look at `fancyhdr` for the headers and footers, `titlesec` for the headings and basic LaTeX formatting commands for the title (you should probably do this yourself). But all in all these are many small aspects, so it would be helpful to know where you struggled.